# IE11 sometimes not displaying entire H1

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, google-font-api

Please take a look at the following test site:
http://adroity.be/ys/test.php

When refreshing the page in IE11 you will notice that sometimes the final 'e' is not showing. It does show as soon as you hover over the title. I don't have access to other versions of IE so I don't know if this is limited to IE11.

I'm using a Google Font (Oswald). Here's the relevant code:

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700'>
  <link rel='stylesheet" href='style.css'>
</head>
  <body>
    <h1><a href="/">YellowSubmarine</a></h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

**STYLE.CSS**

```
body {
  font-family: "Oswald",sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 130px;
}
h1 a {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Frankly I have no clue how to start troubleshooting. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add the __relevant__ code to your post.

Comment: It's gonna be hard to impossible to debug/fix this. Since it is the last letter, did you try to add another character at the end? You could place an `&nbsp;` before and after.

Comment: I've tried adding an `&nbsp;` before and after and this seems to help, but unfortunately this is messing up my design in other browsers. The final page will have more elements aligned with the title.

Comment: I believe the issue is caused because of this CSS `a { transition: all 0.4s ease 0s; }`. Hope this will help you figure it out

Comment: I've tested your theory by removing `a { transition: all 0.4s ease 0s; }` from the stylesheet but the issue remainded.